# Request Body of REST Call using utl_http through Oracle 12c DB having 78000 chars

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle12c

I have tried the following way to make the http call :

```
v_doc_fin clob;

if v_doc_fin is not null then
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_doc_fin);
         req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
         utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
         utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
         utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(v_doc_fin));
         utl_http.write_text(req, v_doc_fin);
         res := utl_http.get_response(req);         
         end if;
```

I tried using the WRITE_RAW and write_text to make the HTTP request, but neither helped.

```
UTL_HTTP.write_text (req, v_doc_fin) ;
UTL_HTTP.WRITE_RAW (r => req, data => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(v_doc_fin));
```

I also tried breaking the request body in chunks, but it didn't help either.

The request within 30000 chars limits are working fine, but when they exceed that limit it fails.

Please suggest or advice on the way to send this request body with such large amount of data in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apex installed in the database maybe using  apex_web_service.make_rest_request is an option for you.
It sends and receives clob data.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI537

Example

```
 l_result_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url         => my_url  
                                                  ,p_http_method => 'POST'
                                                  ,p_body        => l_content_clob);
```

Comment: Yeah, we thought of this option but we don't have this installed in our DB. Please suggest any other alternate if possible.

Comment: This maybe: https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/utl_http-and-a-multipartform-data-request-body/